# How full/traditional does one's highland dress need to be in order to exempt the carrying of a Sgian Dubh/similar style of knife? (UK)

Tags: united-kingdom, weapons, scotland

My work uniform consists of a polo shirt and sweater, but with leg wear of our own choice. So if I was to wear a kilt, sporran, hose and flashes, would that be sufficient to allow me to wear a Sgian Dubh too?

In addition, how traditional must each item be to properly count, or can almost anything be considered a sporran or Sgian Dubh as long as it serves the same function?

Picture for reference: (Kershaw Secret Agent, single sided 4.4" blade)
[image: Kershaw Secret Agent]

Comment: One thing I might start with is whether Highland Dress has a specific legal definition in the UK. In the USA, it would certainly be considered a traditional ethnic costume under the First Amendment and anti-discrimination laws (e.g. a public school trying to ban a student from wearing it), but the determination of whether someone's attire was authentic "enough" would be a question of fact for the jury to be evaluated based on social context and not any specific written description.